# Voice change in react native TSS

Tags: react-native, npm, text-to-speech, voice

I'm currently developing a React Native application that incorporates a text-to-speech (TTS) feature. However, I'm facing challenges finding a suitable package or API that offers a non-robotic voice. I've tried several packages, but all the voices sound artificial and robotic, which is not the experience I want to deliver to my users.

I'm looking for recommendations or suggestions for a React Native TTS package or API that provides a more natural-sounding, human-like voice. Ideally, I would prefer a solution that leverages neural text-to-speech technology or offers high-quality voice synthesis capabilities.

Could anyone please suggest a package or API that meets these requirements? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help